# Show that the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ can be writtin as $TT'$ for some $3 \times 2$ matrix $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    5 &   4   & 0 \\
    4 & 5 & 3  \\
    0 &   3 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$. There is a theorem in my book that is an $m \times m$ nonnegative definite matrix of rank $r$ can be written as $TT'$ for some $m \times r$ matrix $T$. The theorem doesn't describe how to find $T$ though. The matrix above has rank $2$ and is nonnegative definite so I know $T$ exists but don't know where to start to find it. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can diagonalize $A$ by an orthogonal matrix $O$, that is 
$$A = O D O^{-1}=ODO'$$ where $O^{-1}=O'$ and $D$ diagonal with first $k$ diagonal entries $>0$ and the rest $0$.
$$A = (OE)(E'O')=(OE)(OE)'$$
Now the matrix $OE$ has the last $n-k$ columns $0$. Remove them to get $T$. Check that $TT'=(OE)(OE)'=A$.

Comment: So we can write $A$ as $A=XDX'$ where the columns of $X$ and the othonormal eigen vectors and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the diagnoal elements the eigen values. And the we can write $D=FF'$ where $F$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements being the square roots of the diagonal elements of $D$ so then $A=XFF'X'$ and $T=XF$ but then $T$ would be $3 \times 3$. How do I define $O$ and $D$ in your answer ?

Comment: nevermind i get, thank you!